# Nested struct values change without any function acting on them. Help me understand why

Tags: c

A very basic implementation of a linked list where the node is a struct and the nodes value is a nested struct consisting of two `char*`.

I create and link the first 3 nodes in the `main()`. I pass two `char*` and the head of the list to the `addToTail(char* fName, char* lName, NODE* head)` that creates a new node, initializing the value using the two strings, and appends the node to the list.

Still inside `addToTail()` I explicitly print only the 4th node from the head using `head->next->next->next->value.lastName` and it prints what I expected it to be, for both fields of the value;

Execution returns to `main()` where I explicitly print the 4th node using `one.next->next->next->value.lastName`. I do the same for `value.firstName`.

The result: `firstName` is the same as the last print but `lastName` is now a `(null)` and the address of its pointer is `(nil)`. The `lastName` and `firstName` are treated the same, why the different consequences?

I compile using `gcc -ansi -g`.

Link to online code + output(page bottom): https://ideone.com/cZqMFZ

Here is the code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
};

typedef struct LinkedListNode NODE;

struct LinkedListNode {
    struct person value;
    NODE *next;
};

void printlist(NODE *head){
    printf("LINE 16 OF FILE\n");
    printf(
        "4th NODE value: firstName: %s , lastName: %s\n",
        head->value.firstName,
        head->value.lastName
    );
    printf("4th NODE firsname address: %p\n", 
        head->value.firstName
    );
    printf("4th NODE lastName address: %p\n", 
        head->value.lastName
    );

    /* code to print list from head to tail
    NODE *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%s %s\n", current->value.firstName, current->value.lastName);
        current = current->next;
    }*/
}
void addToTail(char* firstName, char* lastName, NODE* head){
    NODE* current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL) current = current->next;
    NODE tail = {
        {
            firstName,
            lastName
        },
        NULL
    };
    current->next = &tail;

    /* printing the 4th node from the head */
    printf("LINE 49 OF FILE\n");
    printf(
        "4th NODE value: firstName: %s , lastName: %s\n",
        head->next->next->next->value.firstName,
        head->next->next->next->value.lastName
    );
    printf("4th NODE firsname address: %p | content: %s\n", 
        head->next->next->next->value.firstName, 
        head->next->next->next->value.firstName
    );
    printf("4th NODE lastName address: %p | content: %s\n", 
        head->next->next->next->value.lastName, 
        head->next->next->next->value.lastName

    );
}

int main(){
    NODE one = {
        {
            "1 FirstName",
            "1 LastName"
        },
        NULL
    };
    NODE two = {
        {
            "2 FirstName",
            "2 LastName"
        },
        NULL
    };
    NODE three = {
        {
            "3 FirstName",
            "3 LastName"
        },
        NULL
    };
    two.next = &(three);
    one.next = &(two);

    /* using addToTail() to add another node to the list */
    addToTail("qwerty","QWERTY", &one);

    /* AFTER the 4th node has been added to the list - back in main() */
    /* printing the 'value' struct of the 4th NODE and the pointer addresses of the two fields of the 'value' */
    printf("LINE 96 OF FILE\n");
    printf(
        "4th NODE value: firstName: %s , lastName: %s\n",
        one.next->next->next->value.firstName,
        one.next->next->next->value.lastName
    );
    printf("4th NODE firsname address: %p | content: %s\n", 
        one.next->next->next->value.firstName, 
        one.next->next->next->value.firstName
    );
    printf("4th NODE lastName address: %p | content: %s\n", 
        one.next->next->next->value.lastName, 
        one.next->next->next->value.lastName

    );

    /* passing the 4th NODE as the head of a list to be printed */
    printlist(one.next->next->next);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your use of `%s` versus `%p` might be causing some issues with the type of value expected for the printout.

Comment: @HoratiusCocles - Is my use inappropriate? I use the same formatting strings for `printf()`s in the first print-block(line 49) and the second (line 96). It seems to me that its the data thats messed up.

Comment: You don't copy the data passed to `addToTail()` so if the original data is overwritten by the next line, the data in the list changes too.  Make copies of the data passed to the function — maybe using `strdup()`.  That has consequences for freeing the list too.  It is mildly surprising that you're using 'all constant' data, so this may not be the main problem with the current code, but it would become a problem if you read the data from a file, for example.

Comment: I'm not reproducing your problem with a variant of yo9ur code which makes the two functions static (so I don't get complaints about the functions not being declared before being defined — my default compiler options require that), and using `int main(void)` so that it is a prototype definition, not an old-style (pre-standard, aka K&R) definition.  I enabled the 'print the current list' code too, and called `printlist(&one);` at the end of `main()` and got the expected output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - `addToTail()` creates a new struct variable and passes its address to the `next*` of the 3rd node. Nowhere after this point do I write anything in this program. Could it be that after `addToTail()` is done some of the memory it used, to create the 4th node, is released?

Comment: However, when I add `-fsanitize=address` to my compilation options, I get: `==86379==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffeeb852408 at pc 0x0001043ae7d7 bp 0x7ffeeb852300 sp 0x7ffeeb8522f8
READ of size 8 at 0x7ffeeb852408 thread T0` —
    `#0 0x1043ae7d6 in main ll71.c:98` —

`Address 0x7ffeeb852408 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 232 in frame`
—    `#0 0x1043ae0af in main ll71.c:67`.   Etc.  That's not good.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - didn't see your second comment. Will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's almost certainly what the `-fsanitize=address` report is trying to tell you.  It is surprising that you're not using `malloc()` et al — lists normally require that.  I do occasionally create lists without using dynamic memory allocation, but you have to be so careful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - My 5th day of studying C - no idea what am I doing. I will look into fixing it. Thank you very much for you input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the function returns, the stack memory will disappear, the content is undetermined.

In the `addToTail` function, you should use `malloc` to allocate heap memory instead of using stack memory via local variable `tail`, and allocate memory for the tail's firstName & lastName, copy the firstName's content to the tail's firstName, copy the lastName's content to the tail's lastName.